# The ratio of the multiplication of two independent Exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am new here and I really need your help.

Suppose I have two independent exponential random variables, lets say $X_1$ and $X_2$ with $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ parameters.  What will be the probability such that

$P\{[X_1\ X_2/(X_1\ X_2 + 1)] < c\}$ where $c$ is a constant?

I went through the derivations but I think I am doing it wrong!  So, any hint will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recognizing that $0<c<1$, perform the full integral to find that answer involves a Bessel function of the first kind, $K_1$:

$1-2 \sqrt{-\frac{c}{c-1}} \sqrt{\text{$\lambda_1$} \text{$\lambda_2$}} K_1\left(2
   \sqrt{-\frac{c}{c-1}} \sqrt{\text{$\lambda_1$} \text{$\lambda_2$}}\right)$

This figure should clarify:

[image]

The function is $p(x1, x2) \propto e^{- \lambda_1 x} e^{-\lambda_2 x}$, and the boundary is defined by ${x1\ x2 \over x1\ x2 + 1} <c$.

I'll leave the rest to you....

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Can I ask you about the result. Actually, this probability will give me the outage probability, this means if the P[{}<c], then the system is in outage. Now, in your answer, c should not exceed 1 which is not the case in my system. c will be always be larger than 1. One more thing please, can you show me the steps of derivations or the major steps. As I you told you earlier, I am new here and I can't type the equations I have on my papers. Thanks again.